# Error in creating alias in formula tag

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a sql query in formula tag inside property tag.

In that query i am creating alias name but the hibernate appends table name and throwing me error.

select sum(e.salary) as sal from employee e

but hibernate changes to

select sum(e.salary) as **employee.sal** from employee e

how to avoid this ....

it should recognise as sal inside of employee.sal !!!

Comment: Could you post your query code and your mapping / annotations?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just declare:

```
<property name="salary" type="integer"
formula="( select sum(e.salary) from employee e )">
</property>
```

What's the point of the alias?

Comment: I have the same problem. I need the alias because I use the query as subquery in another query.